# Problem with refreshing the status of files with VisualSVN and AnkhSVN

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, visualsvn, ankhsvn, visual-c++-2008

We use VisualSVN Server as our Version Control server. We integrated TortoiseSVN into Visual C++ 2008 using VisualSVN.

Now, I want to see if a file is locked by another user. When I press the "Refresh Status" button, nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

I also uninstalled VisualSVN, and installed AnkhSVN instead. The same problem exists here. When I press the "Refresh Status" button (Right click -> Subversion -> Refresh Status), I cannot see any of the changes (none of the icons on the left side of filenames change, no "locked", no "modified", ...). But when I press the "Refresh Pending Changes" button in the "Recent Changes" tab of "Pending Changes" window, its **list** reflects the changes. But I want to see the changes as icons near filenames!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Subversion, and therefor AnkhSVN, aren't designed to communicate the state of other's peoples work to your working copy. The tool is designed for the [copy-modify-merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.vsn-models.copy-merge) way of working, meaning you update your working copy, make the required change, and commit those.

If someone else modified the files in the meantime, you'll get notified of that at commit time, then you update, and in most cases the files are automatically merged. Worst case is that you have to resolve conflicts, which isn't very hard when you [set up a proper merge tool](http://ankhsvntips.net/post/1462457755/setting-up-diff-merge-tools). I personally use [SourceGear DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) in AnkhSVN, which is free.